# Bit operations converting to an integer

Tags: java

I have some binary operations that are not working like I expect.
I have byte array with the first 2 bytes having these values : 0x5, and 0xE0.
I want to combine them into an integer value that should be 0x5E0.
I tried doing :

```
int val = (b[i]) << 8 | b[i+1];
```

but the value is coming out 0xFFFFFFEE0 and the first byte 0x5 is getting lost

I thought this would be easy? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RedRoboHood this is the same, `<<` has a higher priority.

Comment: Up-voted for "not working like I expect" part  instead of regular "not working correctly" like somebody all of the sudden found serious java bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try: `int val = ((b[i] & 0xff) << 8) | (b[i + 1] & 0xff)`.  Bytes are (unfortunately) signed in Java, so if the high bit is set, it gets sign-extended when converted to an integer.

Comment: If you're using Java 8, there's also `Byte.toUnsignedInt`.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's "unfortunately" ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun I don't know if I've ever found signed byte to be useful, but I know I've made mistakes because they are.  I suppose I could have left out the editorializing :-).

Comment: It is indeed unfortunate that they had to gimp the type system because unsigned integers would apparently have been too difficult to understand for cheap outsourced contractors.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen That's wrong. Java has 7 primitive types, which is already a lot. With unsigned, you'd get 4 more for no gain, as there's no sane way how to define the behavior when unsigned and signed get mixed. Add all the casting stuff and your "cheap outsourced contractors" would have even more problems. And not only they.

Comment: @maaartinus I don't think "for no gain" is accurate. If you need integer semantics modulo 2^N then you need an unsigned type. If you need a larger range for a value that will never be negative without making your objects larger then you need an unsigned type. If you don't want sign extension then you need an unsigned type. C has rules for mixing signed and unsigned integers and they're indeed sane. There's no need to cast when the implicit conversion is what you want.

Comment: @0x5f3759df No! Unlike in C, in Java signed integer works mod `2**N` perfectly well. +++ By using unsigned you gain just one bit - how often is that what you need? +++ For unsigned extension, masking can be used trivially (I'm using my own methods so I don't need to count the `F`s). +++ The C signedness mixing rules are only sane by C sanity standards. 9 out of 10 therapists would disagree. +++  An implicit cast is less verbose but often more surprising then an explicit cast. You often get what you want and sometimes you get a bug to hunt down.

Comment: @maaartinus The fact that Java apparently guarantees two's complement integers is convenient. C is still stuck supporting some other integer representations that nobody actually uses for signed types, so only unsigned types are guaranteed to act that way. I think the phrasing of "just one bit" can be a bit misleading here as that translates to "just a couple billion fewer representable values" when you have a 32-bit int. The C signedness rules really aren't that bad. They're not anywhere near JavaScript Truth Table Bad at least, but I digress.

Comment: @maartinus The only case where signed/unsigned comparison is insane is at "highest" precision; and with a sacrifice of efficiency you can make those sane.  Simply block non-explicit converting between unsigned and signed value of the same size.  You could even make out of bounds conversion throw an exception, rather than doing something "unexpected".  (convert a negative integer to an unsigned integer, and you get an out of bounds exception).  It would be a parallel integer system.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `byte` data type is signed. Therefore, `b[i+1]` gets sign-extended before performing the operation, becoming `0xFFFFFFE0`. When it gets OR-ed with `0x0500` from `b[i]<<8`, the `0x0500` gets lost.

You can fix this by AND-ing with `0xFF` before performing the operation:

```
public static int toInt16(byte high, byte low) {
    int res = (high << 8);
    res |= (low & 0xFF);
    return res & 0xFFFF;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/TZjDAF)